# setting CASE statement so all results are Varchar

Tags: sql-server, case

I'm using the query below but get the error

```
'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '8-14' to data type int.'
```

I presume its because the second line is returning an integer and the rest isn't, is that correct?

I'm not going to be calculating of this field so if they all need to be the same type of value, having the second line return as varchar would be fine .I've tried using 'convert' but I don't think I've got my syntax right.

```
,(case when AppointmentCancellationDate = null Then 'NoDate'
when (datediff(day,BasicStartDate,AppointmentCancellationDate)) < '8' then (datediff(day,BasicStartDate,AppointmentCancellationDate))
when (datediff(day,BasicStartDate,AppointmentCancellationDate)) <15 then '8-14'
when (datediff(day,BasicStartDate,AppointmentCancellationDate)) <22 then '15-21'
Else '+22'  end) as CancWindowGroup
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the below:

```
,(case when AppointmentCancellationDate is null Then 'NoDate'
when (datediff(day,BasicStartDate,AppointmentCancellationDate)) <8 then cast(datediff(day,BasicStartDate,AppointmentCancellationDate) as nvarchar(10))
when (datediff(day,BasicStartDate,AppointmentCancellationDate)) <15 then '8-14'
when (datediff(day,BasicStartDate,AppointmentCancellationDate)) <22 then '15-21'
Else '+22'  end) as CancWindowGroup
```

Comment: and change from `< '8'` to `< 8`

Comment: And change `= null ` to `is null`

Comment: Thanks for the updates, they have been made.  @r.baton feel free to check the accept answer button if it worked for you.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

with 'NoDate' you define the result of the case as varchar. the second line produces int - so there is the type clash.